# stopPropagation() of a different event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, stoppropagation, event-propagation

How can I listen to a `change` event on a checkbox without triggering a `click` event on its container?

```
<label><input type="checkbox"> Hello world</label>
```

I want to trigger an action on the checkbox's `change` event, but I don't want it to bubble up to a `click` event on the label.

```
(function ($) {
    $('input').change(function (v) {
        v.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('label').click(function () {
        alert('You should not see this message if you click the checkbox itself!');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r49PA/

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Bind a `click` event to the `input` that stops propagaion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that two events are triggered when you click the checkbox -- a `change` and a `click`. You're only catching the `change`, so the click isn't ever being told to stop propagation. You need to either add a second handler on the checkbox for click events, or combine one handler to catch both types, like  this:

```
$('input').on('change, click', function (v) {
    v.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle demonstrating a combined handler: http://jsfiddle.net/r49PA/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can stop propagation on `click` event instead of `change` event since you bind `click` event for the parent `label`:

```
$('input').click(function (v) {
    v.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r49PA/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

With **plain javascript** you can do something like this:

```
var stopPropagation = false;    

selector.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) { 
  // simulating hold event
  setTimeout(function() {
    stopPropagation = true;

    // do whatever you want on the `hold` event

  })
}

selector.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
  if (stopPropagation) { event.stopPropagation(); return false; }

  // regular event code continues here...

}
```

Since `mousedown` and `click` events are overlapping, we want the `click` event to not be triggered when we are trying to get the `hold` state. This little helper flag variable `stopPropagation` does the trick.